# How to add datatable pager template to Angular ngx datatable

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-template, angular6, ngx-datatable

I am trying to create a custom pagination for swimlane ngx datatable (https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable).

Custom template for the footer is working fine (as per documentation: http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#footer), and the pagination is also working as expected, but notice that the  DOM component has a  with custom pager code in it. This is not appearing on the frontend, because it seems that the  component does not accept custom templating.

Does anyone know, what is the right way to add a custom template to ngx-datatable's datatable pager?

My specific problem is, that I need to change the default left and right  elements to fontawesome components, but maybe I would also like to make some other cosmetic or functional changes there.

My code is.

```
<ngx-datatable
                        *ngIf="(files | objectPropertyLikeStringPipe:fileNameLikeDataContract | objectHasTagPipe:searchTags:'tags').length"
                        class="classic show-overflow"
                        bbsNgxResizeWatcher
                        [rowHeight]="undefined"
                        [columnMode]="'flex'"
                        (activate)="tableActivate($event)"
                        [rows]="files | objectPropertyLikeStringPipe:fileNameLikeDataContract | objectHasTagPipe:searchTags:'tags'"
                        [sorts]="[{prop:'type',dir:'asc'},{prop:'fileName',dir:'asc'}]"
                        [columns]="columns"
                        [selected]="selected"
                        [selectionType]="'checkbox'"
                        (select)="onSelect($event)"
                        [limit]="2"
                        [footerHeight]="50"
                >
                    <ngx-datatable-footer>
                        <ng-template
                                ngx-datatable-footer-template
                                let-rowCount="rowCount"
                                let-pageSize="pageSize"
                                let-selectedCount="selectedCount"
                                let-curPage="curPage"
                                let-offset="offset"
                                let-isVisible="isVisible">
                            <div class="page-count">
                                <span *ngIf="selectedMessage">
                                  {{selectedCount.toLocaleString()}} {{selectedMessage}} /
                                </span>
                                {{rowCount.toLocaleString()}} {{totalMessage}}
                            </div>
                            <datatable-pager
                                    #ngxDatatablePager
                                    [pagerLeftArrowIcon]="'datatable-icon-left'"
                                    [pagerRightArrowIcon]="'datatable-icon-right'"
                                    [pagerPreviousIcon]="'datatable-icon-prev'"
                                    [pagerNextIcon]="'datatable-icon-skip'"
                                    [page]="curPage"
                                    [size]="pageSize"
                                    [count]="rowCount"
                                    [hidden]="!((rowCount / pageSize) > 1)"
                                    (change)="ngxDatatable.onFooterPage($event)">
                                <ng-template>
                                    <ul class="pager">
                                        <li [class.disabled]="!ngxDatatablePager.canPrevious()" [class.target-p]="true">
                                            <a
                                                    role="button"
                                                    aria-label="go to first page"
                                                    href="javascript:void(0)"
                                                    (click)="ngxDatatablePager.selectPage(1)">

                                                <fa-icon    [icon]="['fal', 'angle-left']"
                                                ></fa-icon>
                                                <p>asdklslac</p>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li [class.disabled]="!ngxDatatablePager.canPrevious()">
                                            <a
                                                    role="button"
                                                    aria-label="go to previous page"
                                                    href="javascript:void(0)"
                                                    (click)="ngxDatatablePager.prevPage()">
                                                <i class="{{pagerLeftArrowIcon}}"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li
                                                role="button"
                                                [attr.aria-label]="'page ' + pg.number"
                                                class="pages"
                                                *ngFor="let pg of pages"
                                                [class.active]="pg.number === page">
                                            <a
                                                    href="javascript:void(0)"
                                                    (click)="ngxDatatablePager.selectPage(pg.number)">
                                                {{pg.text}}-1
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li [class.disabled]="!ngxDatatablePager.canNext()">
                                            <a
                                                    role="button"
                                                    aria-label="go to next page"
                                                    href="javascript:void(0)"
                                                    (click)="ngxDatatablePager.nextPage()">
                                                <i class="{{pagerRightArrowIcon}}"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li [class.disabled]="!ngxDatatablePager.canNext()">
                                            <a
                                                    role="button"
                                                    aria-label="go to last page"
                                                    href="javascript:void(0)"
                                                    (click)="ngxDatatablePager.selectPage(totalPages)">
                                                <i class="{{pagerNextIcon}}"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </ng-template>
                            </datatable-pager>
                        </ng-template>
                    </ngx-datatable-footer>

                </ngx-datatable>
```

Visual output (PS! the pagination is still default. It is not using my pagination ng-template!):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to "pager.component.ts" - you can't custom it ('datatable-pager' component).
You may try to create your own one with the similar behavior.

Comment: Do you know of a way, how to create my own pager and have ngx-datatable use that?

Comment: Here is a quick example how i use it in my project. I've 
created additional layer for the whole table to make it easier to reuse. In my case i've used 'datatable-pager' componenent from the box but in u'r case u can create u'r own one and bind it in the way how i did that.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqjq9t